# How to display two backslashes in a row in bold?

Tags: bug, markdown

In a recent question I posted I wanted to highlight two consecutive bkslashes in the middle of a folder path.  This was not inside any type of code blocks, just regular text.

The desired result is to display C:\somepath\\restofpath\ but bold the two bkslashes in a row which are between somepath and restofpath.

I've **tried** the following so far:

- `C:\somepath**\\**restofpath\`

  > C:\somepath**\**restofpath\
- `C:\somepath**\\\\**restofpath\`

  > C:\somepath**\\**restofpath\
- `C:\somepath**\\****\\**restofpath\`

  > C:\somepath**\****\**restofpath\

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just drop back to HTML for the bolding.

```
Foo<strong>\\\\</strong>Bar
```

Foo**\\**Bar

Comment: Thank you Billy.  I don't know why I didn't think of that my self.  Sometimes it is easier to just write the html tags that markdown was invented to avoid.

Comment: If you mean it to be bold, use <b>. Use <strong> if you want it to be understood as strongly emphasized (and usually rendered as bold, but that's a presentation detail).

Comment: @mattdm The <b> tag doesn't even really mean bold any more anyway, since HTML5 moved away from tags that mean presentational stuff. It's now specifically for (quoting the MDN docs) "keywords... whose typical presentation would be boldfaced". I just sorta ignored all that, and went for the actual tag that Markdown produces when you use double-asterisks, since that's what the question was looking for, anyway.